# Redrawing endpoints using jsPlumb

Tags: angularjs, jsplumb, endpoints

I have been stuck with this a few days and want your help to know how to tackle this problem.
I created this application something like a flowchart to draw different types of plumb items with different endpoints attached to them. After it is being created as an element the endpoints are added dynamically according to the type of plumb item. is it like the following.

This is how I create the plumb items.

```
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.setAttribute("id",schema_id);
    element.setAttribute("class","item " +control.Type);
    element.setAttribute("style","left:" +posX + "px ; top: "+posY+"px");

    var output = document.getElementById('container');
    output.appendChild(element);
```

And then I add the endpoints according to its type.

```
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint(element,<the style goes here>,{ anchor:<the location of the endpoint goes here>, uuid: <a new ID is created for this>});
```

And this is what it looks like

[Screen One](http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn39/tistus/2015-03-26_11-21-54_zpsknbhlycx.jpg)

I managed to grabbed the data from the method "GetConnections" and get it saved in the DB as a JSON. This JSON includes all the IDs which are for plumb items and all the endpoints.

But when I try to retrieve it back again to the UI, it appears like this. Everything appears great except the endpoints.

[Screen Two](http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn39/tistus/2015-03-26_11-29-14_zpso6rpibqr.jpg)

On redraw, the endpoints are created in the same way mentioned above. To reconnect the endpoints I am using this code.

```
    jsPlumb.connect({ source:<source id>, target:<target id>,anchors:<location of the endpoint>,<style>);
```

**The problem :**

For the above code, Although I give the UUID of the endpoint to the source and target, it doesn't identify it as endpoints to connect from and to.

Is there a way to find the ID and get them connected? What I found out was that only the plumb items could be searched with "getElementById" with the UUID but not the endpoints.

The problem is how to make these endpoints get connected as originally drawn. How can connect each endpoint back again? I have all the IDs and when they are redrawn they are having the same IDs as it had when it was saved. But I couldn't find a way to connect the endpoints back again separately since this has different types of endpoints specific to each plumb item.

Any suggestions?

Sorry for the long post
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [the connect method](http://jsplumb.org/apidocs/classes/jsPlumb.html#method_connect)

If you connect ids, or elements, or Endpoints use

```
 jsPlumb.connect({source:<source id>, target:<target id>});
```

but if you connect array of UUIDs of the two Endpoints use

```
jsPlumb.connect({uuids:<array of uuids>});
```

Comment: Thank you. jsPlumb.connect({uuids:<array of uuids>}); did the work :)